# TikaConfig.getDefaultConfig(); causes

Tags: java, apache-tika, exiftool

When calling the line....

TikaConfig tikaConfig = TikaConfig.getDefaultConfig();

... I am getting the following error

Cannot run program "exiftool": error=2, No such file or directory

From what I understand exiftool is used to pull metadata from image, audio, and video files.

To get around this do I need to install exiftool? or better yet can I add it to my pom?

Is there a way to exclude it?

I read about using a tika-config.xml file to exclude the parser but I did not see a lot of good examples. Where would this xml file need to live in my proejct?
Would I still call TikaConfig.getDefaultConfig(); or do I need to point directly to the xml file.

Thanks in advance.

My Pom...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
    <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.25</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
    <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
    <version>1.25</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Have you added any External Parser config files?

Comment: I have not added any External Parser config files.

Comment: I dug a little deeper into the tika-core code.

There is a tika-external-parsers.xml file that gets read in. It defines external parsers, including exiftool. The parsers it defines can have check tags. So when we call TikaConfig.getDefaultConfig(), there is a point in the tika code where it runs a check to see if exiftool exists ( “exiftool -ver” ).  Since it does not exist an IOException is thrown.  The exception is immediately caught in ExternalParser.java, and the catch statement returns false to the previous method and processing continues.  I am not sure why the stack is logged out.

Comment: The stack may be logged out by a dependency we have in the project for logging. I will submit a formal answer once I figure out our approach.